# MonoDroid:INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin.android

Using MonoDroid 4.0.6 and MonoDevelop, any attempt to run in an emulator fails with this error listed below:

The minSdkVersion matches the emulator's SDK version. All AVDs were created by the MonoDroid isntaller.

```
Detecting package list location

Getting package list from device

Installing shared runtime package on device
1849 KB/s (25866362 bytes in 13.657s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk
Success

Installing the platform framework
1565 KB/s (16530851 bytes in 10.310s)
pkg: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Failed to install the platform framework
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this in 2 ways.

1) In the manifest the minSdkVersion should match or be lower than the emulator
2) (what tripped me up) The Mono DLLs References of the project should be set to the Android version too.

Both are needed. I come from a Java Android background so never thought to change anything but the manifest.